# How can i populate a change of a property in a Component in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: web-component, vaadin-flow

I have following class for a little visible spinner:

```java
@Tag("granite-spinner")
@NpmPackage(value = "@granite-elements/granite-spinner", version = "3.0.0")
@JsModule("@granite-elements/granite-spinner/granite-spinner.js")
public class BusyComponent extends Component implements HasEnabled {
    @Override
    public void onEnabledStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
        getElement().setProperty("active", enabled);
    }
}
```

That's called in my MainView:

```java
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Project Base", shortName = "Project Base")
@Push
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements PageConfigurator {
    public MainView() {
        UI currUI = UI.getCurrent();
        final BusyComponent bc = new BusyComponent();
        final Button button = new Button("Click me");
        button.addClickListener(event -> {
            button.setEnabled(false);
            bc.setEnabled(true);
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                currUI.access(() -> {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                    bc.setEnabled(false);
                });
            }).start();
        });
        add(bc);
        add(button);
    }
}
```

The button gets disabled the moment i click and enabled after 3s. But the Spinner continues spinning. Somehow the Property change is not updated. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** You've done everything right. There is nothing wrong with your code and it seems webcomponent doesn't react to an attribute change

**Longer version:**

I've tried this web-component outside a Vaadin project and it doesn't work the way you expect it to work, unfortunately.
Also, it states in [description](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@granite-elements/granite-spinner/elements/granite-spinner#property-active):

> active: boolean | null | undefined
>   If true spinner is shown

(So it doesn't imply separately that the visibility is updated after set once..)

An example here [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wxr9sk6f/1/)

Thus, there is nothing wrong with our Vaadin code and `active` property is removed/added correctly on a button click, if you check in devTools.

It seems that web-component simply doesn't react to the property change after it has been rendered once. If you look in its implementation code, property `active` is used in `render()` function only [Code in unpkg](https://unpkg.com/@granite-elements/granite-spinner@3.0.0/granite-spinner.js).

I am not a expert in web-components, so not sure how it should be implemented otherwise,but maybe you could create a bug report to a component's Github repo? Feel free to re-use example JSFiddle, if you want : )